# class with initialization list initiated std::array member variable

Tags: c++

In c++17 you can do

```
std::array a{ "one", "two", "three" };
```

and get a `std::array<const char*, 3>`.  Awesome!

Because array member variables must have their size specified in the class declaration this is not usable as a class variable.  I would like to create a class with one of these arbitrarily long initialization list initialized arrays and one or more `constexpr` methods. I would expect the only constructor to take the initialization list as an argument.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `std::array` is usable as class field just fine. But if you need variable size array then you need `std::vector`

Comment: std::vercot is unsuitable due to compile-time initialization requirements.  The array size would be fixed per instance, but may be different in different instances.

Comment: @MichaelSurette Oh, it's suitable alright. It has stood the test of time just fine.

Comment: If you know array size at compile time then what is the problem with using `std::array`?

Comment: I would like to have the size of the initialization list be the size of the array, removing the requirement to count the entries, which may be a source of errors, especially on updates.

Comment: @Ron, It's stood the test of time for runtime uses. No `std::vector` has ever been used when compile-time initialization is required (though it might be constexpr soon).

Comment: @Ron I was under the impression that vectors were not constexpr compatible.

Comment: @MichaelSurette Indeed they don't have constexpr constructors.

Comment: Then you can make your class a template class deducing array size from initialization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a class templated on the size of the array (and the element type if you want), that has a variadic constructor. Something like this:

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct custom_array {
    std::array<T, N> data;

    template <typename... Args>
    constexpr explicit custom_array(Args... args) : data{args...} {
    }
};
```

To be able to deduce `N` you also need a deduction guide like this:

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
explicit custom_array(Args... args) -> custom_array<std::common_type_t<Args...>, sizeof...(Args)>;
```

You can find a complete example [on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/TO4i8S).

Comment: Thank you for this worthy effort, it does however still suffer from the same issue as std::array in that you have to declare the initialization list in the class definition.  This necessitates a separate class for each instance.  It is an improvement in that the methods can be integrated into the template. Definitely worth studying to see if I can get around this limitation.

Comment: So you want `std::array`s of different sizes in the same non-template class? I'm afraid that's not possible.

Comment: I don't mind a template class, just not a whole new class for each initialization list. If what I'm looking for is not possible, then I am a bit disappointed, but it is what it is.

Comment: It's a new instantiation for each type-size combination, that's true. It's not possible because arrays of different sizes are entirely different types. What you could do is to put most of your logic in a non-template base class and use virtual member functions to abstract the size-dependent parts of the concrete classes away.